# Google Calendar API v3, can't figure out how to share a calendar without it sending an email

Tags: php, calendar, google-api, google-api-php-client

Literally what the title says! I can't figure out if there is anyway or option to shut this off!!!

Everytime I add a new ACL rule (through the PHP library to allow someone to access a calendar, it sends that person an email. I have to add the same person to three or four different calendars, and that means they will receive three or four different emails.

Does anyone know of ANY way to shut this off, either in the API, or with the actual website?

Answer (score 0):

The API doesnt allow you to shut that off, for each new rule user is going to be notified.